# How to enable MFP 8.0 secure direct update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I've follow [Configuring the MobileFirst Server Keystore](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/configuring-the-mobilefirst-server-keystore/).
However the app still able to direct update even the public key is not included in the app.

Is that any steps I missed out to enable the secure direct update?

Comment: Direct update can be secured. This means it works even when it is not secured. Have you followed all the instructions to secure the direct update at the client side ? And followed the instructions in https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/#secure-direct-update

Comment: I've followed the instructions in the website. Seem like the app must configure the public key in order to enable secure direct update. If the app didn't configure the public key, the app is still able to direct update.